# How to run a single test, and still access resources defined in test suite?

Tags: java, junit

I created a test suite, with a @ClassRule to open the connection etc. Now I can run all my tests, and connection is opened only once.

But now, when I try to run a single test, I get an error, because connection was not opened. How can I solve this?

Code that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({MyTestCase.class})
public class MyTestSuite {

    public static String connection = null;

    @ClassRule
    public static ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {

        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {
            connection = "connection initialized";
        };

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            connection = null;
        };
    };
}
```

.

```
public class MyTestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.notNull(MyTestSuite.connection);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: current solution after @Jens Schauder suggestions. Works, but looks ugly. Is there a better way?

```
public class ConnectionRule extends ExternalResource {

    private static ConnectionRule singleton = null;
    private static int counter = 0;

    private String connection = null;

    public static ConnectionRule newInstance(){
        if(singleton == null) {
            singleton = new ConnectionRule();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        if(counter == 0){
            System.out.println("init start");
            connection = "connection initialized";

        }
        counter++;
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        counter--;
        if(counter == 0){
            System.out.println("init end");
            connection = null;
        }
    };

    public String getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }     
}
```

.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({MyTestCase.class, MyTestCase2.class})
public class MyTestSuite {

    @ClassRule 
    public static ConnectionRule rule = ConnectionRule.newInstance();
}
```

.

```
public class MyTestCase {

    @ClassRule 
    public static ConnectionRule rule = MyTestSuite.rule;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.notNull(rule.getConnection());
    }
}
```

MyTestCase2 is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rule on the test, instead of the TestSuite.

You might extend the rule so that:

- it does not recreate a connection if it is already there
- keeps a reference to the connection, so the connection can get reused by later tests.
- the reference to the connection you keep between tests might be a [soft or weak one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html).

Comment: I will have multiple test cases, I would like to avoid copy/pasting the rule to each...

Comment: The only thing that you you'd copy is something like @ClassRule ConnectionRule rule = ConnectionRule.instance(); Shouldn't be to bad. You could even extract it in a superclass, although I don't recommend that.

Comment: Implemented it like you suggested (see edit). Now the problem is, since I have class rule in multiple test cases, connection get opened/closed multiple times.

Comment: Just only open the connection if it isn't already open. And don't close it after the test. The connection will get closed when the JVM shuts down, which should be fine for tests.

Comment: Opening is not a problem. A problem is to know, when to close.

Comment: Added a static counter to the ConnectionRule class. Now it appears to work. What could possibly go wrong..?